# jQuery Initiate menu click function at the top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I created a pure css hamburger menu activated at `max-width: 899px` and used jQuery to add a couple of functions to it such as pushing the main content down on click of the hamburger menu, initiating the menu click on `nav-link` click and also initiating menu click on document click but I soon realized that it wasn't still ideal as when the document is scrolled and the menu is clicked, the content keeps getting pushed down and this also affected my on-page link navigation as well, since clicking a `nav-link` initiates menu click which in turn pushes the main content and my link ends up at an offset of where it's supposed to be.
I tried to fix this issue by only pushing down the main content when the user is at the top of the page but this doesn't work as intended since the only method I could find to accomplish this was a `$(window).scroll(function()` which is a scroll function and when a new user visits the page and doesn't scroll, they technically are at the top of the page but yet the function isn't initiated until the user scrolls down and then scrolls up to the top of the page, and even still, it doesn't always work.(I added a console log to indicate when the user has scrolled to the top of the page and you can see that the intended function seems to execute randomly even at the top of the page)
The second problem has to do with the `nav-link` navigation. I still haven't figured a way to prevent the main content push when navigating on-page. I have an idea to execute the main content push first, *then* navigate to the on-page link, but I don't know enough Javascript/jQuery to implement something like that.
*P.S. You can comment out the MODIFIED script to push down the menu on click and un-comment the initial script to see the original behaviour before I implemented my modification.*

```js
//Script to momentarily stop transition when window is resized
(function() {
  const classes = document.body.classList;
  let timer = null;
  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    if (timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = null;
    } else {
      classes.add('stop-transition');
    }
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      classes.remove('stop-transition');
      timer = null;
    }, 100);
  });
})();
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Script to push the section down on menu click

  /*  $(".menu-btn").click(function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     $(".main-content").toggleClass("open");
   
   }); */

  //MODIFIED SCRIPT TO PUSH SECTION DOWN ON MENU CLICK WHEN AT THE TOP OF THE PAGE

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
      console.log('top-page');
    }
    $(".menu-btn").click(function(e) {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(".main-content").toggleClass("open");
      } else if ($(window).scrollTop() != 0 && ($((".main-content")).hasClass("open"))) {
        $(".main-content").removeClass("open");
      }
    });
  });

  // Script to collapse menu on link click

  $(".nav-link").click(function(e) {
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 899px)').matches) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $(".menu-btn").click();
    }
  });

  //Script to close the menu on window/document click

  var $document = $(document);
  $document.click(function(e) {
    if (!$('.menu-btn').is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the button...
      &&
      ($(('.menu-btn')).is(":checked"))) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.menu-btn').click();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: fit-content;
}

html {
  scroll-padding-top: 65px;
  /* height of sticky header */
}

body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  color: #222222;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 65px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

/* Hide blue background on logo tap on some mobile devices */

.logo a {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

#header-img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}

/* Navigation */

nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Hamburger menu button */

.menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.menu-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -42px;
  left: -25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 24px 14px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navicon {
  background-color: #222222;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 26px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

.navicon:before,
.navicon:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #222222;
  transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

.navicon:before {
  top: 9px;
}

.navicon:after {
  bottom: 9px;
}

/* Hamburger Menu Animation Start */

.menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 0;
}

.menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  bottom: 0;
}

.menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
  transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

/* Hide blue background on hamburger menu tap on some mobile devices */

.menu-icon,
.menu-btn,
.navicon {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}


/* Nav items */

.menu {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 65px;
  padding: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0.3192s ease-in-out, opacity 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

/* Below defines properties for a sibling of .menu-btn when it is checked called .menu  */

.menu-btn:checked~nav .menu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: visibility 0.3192s ease-in-out, opacity 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

/* Stop playing transition momentarily on viewport resize. */

body.stop-transition .menu {
  transition: none;
}

.menu li {
  border-top: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
  padding: 10px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu a {
  color: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu-btn:checked~nav .menu a,
.menu-btn:checked~nav .menu li {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

/* MAIN CONTENT  */

.main-content {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

/* For jquery */

.main-content.open {
  margin-top: 195px;
  transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

/* First section */

section.hero {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#form input[type="email"] {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#email:focus {
  outline: rgb(224, 123, 0) auto 1px;
}

#form input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 15px 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  color: #222222;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#submit:focus {
  outline: rgb(224, 123, 0) auto 1px;
}

/**************************/

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Features Section  */

#features {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.icon {
  color: rgb(224, 123, 0);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.desc h2,
.desc p {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

/* How it works section */

#how-it-works {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#video {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 560px;
  height: 315px;
}

img.video-alt {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* Pricing Section */

#pricing {
  margin-top: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.card:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.card-header {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.card h2 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.card ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 15px 0;
  line-height: 2;
}

.btn {
  margin: 15px 0;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(224, 123, 0);
  color: white;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: rgb(224, 123, 0) auto 1px;
}

/* Footer */

footer {
  margin-top: 40px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

footer ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

footer li {
  padding: 10px;
}

footer a {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  color: #222222;
}

footer span {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
}


/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 900px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {

  /* Header  */
  header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

  .logo {
    width: 60vw;
    margin-top: 0;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }

  .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }

  nav {
    width: 40vw;
    margin-top: 0;
  }

  .menu {
    width: 100%;
    transform: none;
    transition: none;
    position: static;
    margin: 0;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .menu li {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: none;
  }

  .menu a {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }

  /* Main content */
  h2 {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }

  .container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  /* Features */
  .row {
    flex-direction: row;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .icon {
    margin: 0;
    width: 20%;
    height: 130px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .desc {
    width: 80%;
    height: 130px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .desc h2,
  .desc p {
    margin: 0;
  }

  /* Pricing */
  #pricing {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .card {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 40px;
  }

  .card:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c8896db64e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<main id="main">
  <header id="header">

    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#">
        <img id="header-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/original_trombones.png" alt="original trombones logo">
      </a>
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
    <label for="menu-btn" class="menu-icon"><span class="navicon"></span></label>

    <nav id="nav-bar">

      <ul class="menu" id="menu">
        <li><a href="#features" class="nav-link">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#how-it-works" class="nav-link">How it Works</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pricing" class="nav-link">Pricing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>

  <div class="main-content">

    <section class="hero">
      <h2>Handcrafted, home-made masterpieces</h2>
      <form action="" id="form">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Get Started" id="submit">
      </form>
    </section>

    <div class="container">

      <section id="features">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="icon">
            <i class="far fa-gem fa-3x"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
            <h2>Premium Materials</h2>
            <p>Our trombones use the shiniest brass which is sourced locally. This will increase the longevity of your purchase.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-truck fa-3x"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
            <h2>Fast Shipping</h2>
            <p>We make sure you receive your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="icon">
            <i class="fas fa-clipboard-check fa-3x"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="desc">
            <h2>Quality Assurance</h2>
            <p>For every purchase you make, we will ensure there are no damages or faults and we will check and test the pitch of your instrument.</p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="how-it-works">
        <iframe id="video" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/y8Yv4pnO7qc?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        <img class="video-alt" src="" alt="Youtube video">

      </section>
      <section id="pricing">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">Tenor Trombone</div>
          <h2>$600</h2>
          <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
          </ol>
          <button class="btn">Select</button>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">Bass Trombone</div>
          <h2>$900</h2>
          <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
          </ol>
          <button class="btn">Select</button>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">Valve Trombone</div>
          <h2>$1200</h2>
          <ol>
            <li>Plays similar to a Trumpet.</li>
            <li>Great for Jazz Bands.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
          </ol>
          <button class="btn">Select</button>
        </div>
      </section>

    </div>

  </div>
  <footer>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <span>© Copyright 2020 Original Trombones</span>
  </footer>

</main>
```

I also provided a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L7pfzont/) to work with.

Comment: I am trying to clearly understand what you are asking for. You want the hamburger menu div to open ontop of the other content, without it pushing anything down???

Comment: Only when the user is _not_ at the top of the page.

Comment: So if the user scrolls down even a single pixle you then want the div to push the content down? or does the user need to scroll to a certain point?

Comment: That means 1px from the top is not at the top of the page, Okay I can do this for you. Gimme 10mins.

Comment: When the user is at the top of the page, I want the menu to push the content down and when the user scrolls, the menu doesn't need to push the content down, it can just overlay the content.

Comment: I cant seem to get your a the hamburger Icon to render, does the CDN require an account? It was rendering then it stoped. Be honest thats why I make all my own ICONS.

Comment: The hamburger icon is a `span`, it should render.
It renders at `max-width: 899px`